# How do i install Slick-carousel in Atom

Tags: package, installation

i've never used packages before and to be frank i really have no idea how they work, i found this package that i wanted to install. Now i got a zip-file and i don't know what to do with it. Tried unzipping it into the atom packages folder but it gives me an error "Cannot find module 'Jquery'. The github page says alot of stuff but i really don't know what it means.

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

Some help would be great, feels like this should be far easier than i believe it is.

Comment: As I understand it, this carousel is something you use on a website. A lot of people use package managers or automated build utilities to create the final  html of the site. This has nothing to do with atom, which is just a text editor. You don't have to use a package manager to use the carousel, just follow the [installation instructions](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Comment: thanks, i followed the instructions and it feels right, but can i not preview the things that slick do locally? i have my html file open in browser now and it does not display content according to the slick website.

Comment: Take a look at your browser console / browser dev tools. In most browser, you can open it with the `F12` key. Are there any errors reported?